# Compare data in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

If next condition is ok: (reserva.desde > '2015-07-03 23:59:59') OR (reserva.hasta < '2015-07-02 00:00:00'). Is showing all.

If back condition is ko but the data "id_vehiculo" is same than back condition, I don't want to show the back data.

My actuality query:

```
select

coches.matricula,
coches.descripcion_es,
grupo.id as id_grupo,
grupo.grupo,
reservas_coches.id_coche as vehiculo_reserva,
reserva.desde,
reserva.hasta,
reserva.id as id_reserva

from

coches
LEFT OUTER JOIN reservas_coches ON reservas_coches.id_coche = coches.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN reservas as reserva ON reserva.id = reservas_coches.id_reserva,
grupos as grupo

where 

coches.id_grupo = grupo.id and
grupo.id = 48 and

((reserva.id IS NULL) OR (reserva.desde > '2015-07-03 23:59:59') OR (reserva.hasta < '2015-07-02 00:00:00'))
```

Comment: Don't mix modern explicit JOIN syntax with old comma separated implicit join syntax. Too confusing!!! Move reserva conditions from WHERE to ON to get true outer join behavior. (As it is now it executes as regular inner join.)

Comment: Yes. Don't use comma-syntax - and definitely don't mix them.